# Pack consecutive duplicates of list elements into sublists in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have seen a question similar to mine in the database but it's nowhere related to my doubt on the code. I am going through the below code and I am stuck because I don't understand `res.last.head!=h`? I searched over the documentation of Scala but I cannot find what is `_.last.head`.

```
  def _pack(res: List[List[A]], rem: List[A]):List[List[A]] = rem match {
    case Nil => res
    case h::tail if (res.isEmpty || res.last.head != h) => _pack(res:::List(List(h)), tail)
    case h::tail => _pack(res.init:::List(res.last:::List(h)), tail)
  }
  _pack(List(),l)
}
println(pack(List(1,1,2,3,3)))
```

Comment: Please note that this is rather poor code and very inefficient, so don't learn bad habits from it!

Comment: Could you please explain more? I am in the learning stages

Comment: Briefly, `last` and `init` require a search of the whole list and are called for each element in the list, so the performance is `O(n^2)` and will get very slow as the input gets longer. It is much faster to build the list in reverse and then reverse the result before returning it. You should also avoid `last` and `head` because they fail on an empty list, prefer `lastOption` and `headOption`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what troubles you there. You can find both in the [`List[A]` ScalaDoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/immutable/List.html).

`List[A]` is a collection that is internally stored as a single linked list with each node (`Cons`) having `head` of type `A` and `tail` of type `List[A]`.

`List[A].last` just returns the last element in the list as the name suggests (note: this is very inefficient as it requires traversal through the whole list from the start). Now since `res` is of type `List[List[A]]`, `res.last` is of type `List[A]`. `List[A].head` is the first element in the list.

To sum up `res.last.head` is the first element of the last `List` stored in list-of-lists `res`.

---

> why there are two case statements with `h::tail`.

You need to learn more about [Pattern matching in Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html) and particularly on "guards". The code in that `match`/`case` can be rewritten as:

```
if (rem == Nil)
    res // first case
else {
  val h = rem.head
  val tail = rem.tail
  if (res.isEmpty || res.last.head != h)
     _pack(res:::List(List(h)), tail) // second case
  else
     _pack(res.init:::List(res.last:::List(h)), tail) // last case
}
```

In other words the code first checks if `rem` is already empty and exits if true. If `rem` is not empty, we take its `head` (`h`) and now we have a choice: does this `h` matches the previous element in the list or not. This `if` is guards the first case, the last case without `if` works as the `else` branch.

Comment: Okay. I understand clearly now but why there are two case statements with h::tail. I do understand first h::tail but whats the use of second case statement?

Comment: @user2708013, I've updated my answer. Hope it helps.